# How to export many rrd files to xml files

Tags: linux, bash, rrdtool, rrd

I have set of old rrd files, so I need to convert them to xml files and again to rrd files in a new server. In order to create xml files from whole directory, I have used following simple bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /varcacti/rra


for i in ./traffic_in*;
do
/usr/local/rrdtool/bin/rrdtool dump $i /home/newuser/rrd_dump_xml/$i.xml;
done
```

This provides a set of xml files but the extension is not what I required actually. This provides,

```
traffic_in_1111.rrd>>>traffic_in_1111.rrd.xml
```

But I need `traffic_in_1111.rrd>>>traffic_in_1111.xml`. can someone help me to modify my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```sh
/home/newuser/rrd_dump_xml/"${i%.rrd}".xml
#..........................^^^^^^^^^^^
```

which removes the rrd extension from the end of the string.

You might want to be more specific with the files you're looping over:

```sh
for i in ./traffic_in*.rrd
```